# how to set cookie with httponly flag in vuejs and vuex that cookie cames from server(Laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, cookies, vuex

I have one VueJs project as front-end and one Laravel project as back-end using for making api and server.

I work with [jwt](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) in laravel, it returns jwt token that contains user info.

**Problem**:

I need to store this token in cookie with HTTPOnly flag but I don't know where and how set this cookie!? In server side (Laravel)?In Client side (VueJs)?

**Codes:**

My AuthController in Laravel:

```
  public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }


  protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type'   => 'bearer',
            'expires_in'   => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }
```

it returns:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC92dWV4LmNhY3R1c3dlYi5pclwvYXBpXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTU3MzkxNDA1NSwiZXhwIjoxNTczODQ3NTQ2YWEiLCJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjozLCJuYW1lIjoiYWxpIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhQGEuY29tIiwicm9sZSI6IjIiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZF9hdCI6bnVsbCwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMTktMTEtMTQgMDg6MDU6NDUiLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAxOS0xMS0xNCAwODowNTo0NSJ9fQ.Ow785CLmaAckZR9iowVkEMX6AxBQw7JSklt3Vp1btAcG4",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

And in my Vuex store actions:

```
const actions = {
    login({commit}, user) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            commit('auth_request');
            Axios.post(`${api_base_url}/login`, user)
            .then(resp => {
                const token = resp.data.access_token;
                commit('auth_success', token, user);
                resolve(resp)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                commit('auth_error');
                reject(err)
                })
            })          

    },
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should create cookie with httponly flag on server. for example, in nodejs + express you do it with `res.cookie("token", token, {httpOnly: true})`. 
also notice, with httponly flag you cant read cookie on client.